# capistrano deploy error - newbie

Tags: ruby, terminal, capistrano

I'm new to ruby and currently having issues deploying with capistrano. below the errors I am getting.

```
cap aborted!
Operation timed out - connect(2)
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `open'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `block in initialize'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `new'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `start'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:156:in `ssh'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:109:in `block in _execute'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:75:in `within'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/stefydu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: The error's coming from net-ssh, giving you a timeout message. What are you connecting to? (where are you deploying to?) Do you have a firewall setup that would cause a timeout? Can you ping wherever you are connecting to without a problem? If you share your deploy.rb (with any important connection details redacted) we might be able to help.

Comment: I know this error quite well. In capistrano 2 everything was fine, but after migrating to version 3 I get this message periodically. Strange thing: Some times it works, some times not. And it happens at various points in the deployment process.

Comment: @Marc I'm having the same issue. Sometimes it makes it through all of the tasks but the last one...Then I change my deploy.rb to only execute that last (previously failing) task and it works just fine. Then I reboot my server, and its all good. Then an hour later, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but an explanation with workaround:

Capistrano 3, and with it sshkit, doesn't reuse existing SSH connections, but start a new one for every task (see https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/34).

Some servers, respectively their firewalls, seem to block new connection requests if they come to fast or if there are too many open connections.

Solutions:

- Fix SSHKit/Capistrano to reuse connections
- Configure your server/firewall to allow tons of parallel ssh sessions (for a simple rails app about 15)
- use my hack below (Disclaimer: no, don't use it):

We're going to extend (monkeypatch) the execute method in gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb. That can be done via the Capfile:

```
# Overwrite execute method to avoid timeouts
class SSHKit::Backend::Netssh
  def execute(*args)
    _execute(*args).success?
  rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
    @tries ||= 0
    raise "Nope, no way" if @tries > 5
    puts "Timeout. yeah. Try it again (#{@tries})" 
    sleep 5
    @tries += 1
    execute(*args)
    end
end
```

This gives the server a chance to breathe...

Comment: No, neither 10 seconds nor 20 seconds do the trick. When I stepped manually through it with byebug it worked though. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I'll edited the hack. This one does actually work. It's still a hack, though. Please consider contributing to sshkit instead of using it...

Comment: This didn't work for me. Need to alter UFW and Fail2Ban settings.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano uses a connection pool for SSH now: 
https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/pull/70